# Pagination For NSTableview in cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, pagination, nstableview

I have an `NSTableView` with 1000+ rows in it. Now I want to add pagination for it and add an limit of 100 in one view, and then place Back and Next button for it to view next data.

I'm new to this cocoa development.
Can anyone help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Implement paging in the NSTableViewDataSource.

Answer (score 0):

Store your data in files. (page0, page1..)

```
 /* page0   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
    <plist version="1.0">
    <array>
        <string>/Volumes/Drop Box</string>
        <string>/Volumes/Backup</string>
        <string>/Users/Music</string>
    </array>
    </plist>*/

#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>


@interface ViewController : NSObject {
    NSTableView *tableView;
    NSMutableArray *mDataSource;
    NSInteger mPageNumber;
    NSInteger mTotalPage;
}
-(IBAction)nextPage : (id)sender;//for next page
-(IBAction)prevPage : (id)sender;// for prev. page
-(void)fetchData;
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSTableView *tableView;
@end
#import "ViewController.h"


@implementation ViewController
@synthesize tableView;
- (id) init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {
        mDataSource = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        mPageNumber=0;
        mTotalPage =2;// total numer of pages
        [self fetchData];
    }
    return self;
}


-(IBAction)nextPage : (id)sender;
{
    ++mPageNumber;
    if (mTotalPage<=mPageNumber) {
        mPageNumber=0;// point to first page
    }
    [self fetchData];

}
-(IBAction)prevPage : (id)sender;
{
    --mPageNumber;
    [self fetchData];
}

-(void)fetchData;
{
    [tableView setDataSource:nil];
    NSString *lDataSourcePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"/page%d",mPageNumber];
    NSArray *lDataSource = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:lDataSourcePath];
    [mDataSource setArray:lDataSource];
    [lDataSource release];
    [lDataSourcePath release];
    [tableView setDataSource:self];
    [tableView reloadData];
}
-(void)dealloc
{
    [mDataSource release];
    [super dealloc];
}

#pragma mark Data Source
- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView
{
    return [mDataSource count];
}

- (id)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)aTableColumn row:(NSInteger)rowIndex
{
    return [mDataSource objectAtIndex:rowIndex];
}

@end
```